# Checking mail in a loop thread goes out of memory

Tags: c#, memory-management, task, imap

I'm using CheckMail task to check the mail every 15 seconds. Every time this task repeats the memory increases. Where is the problem? I'm not instantiating anything.

The Client was inside the thread, so it was called every time. After I take it out nothing changed. Same thing with Senders List.

```
            class MailCheckThread
                {
                    private ImapClient Client;
                    private List<string> Senders;

                    //Thread
                    private Task CheckMail;

                    public MailCheckThread()
                    {
                        Client = new ImapClient("imap.gmail.com", 993, Hemail, Hpassword, AuthMethod.Login, true);
                        Senders = APM_SharedClasses.MailSender.Sender();
                        MailTimer_Thread();
                        Console.WriteLine("Creating mail check thread!");
                        CheckMail.Start();
                    }

            private void MailTimer_Thread()
                    {
                        CheckMail = new Task(() =>
                        {
                            while (true)
                            {
                                IEnumerable<uint> uids = Client.Search(
                                SearchCondition.From(Senders[0]));

                                if (uids.Count() > 0)
                                {
                                    MailMessage msg = Client.GetMessage(uids.First());

                                    Console.WriteLine($"Message from : {msg.From} | Subject : {msg.Subject} | Body : {msg.Body}");
                                }
                                Thread.Sleep(15000);
                            }
                        });
                    }
            }
```

How can I optimize the code in this case? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with what you posted, are you sure there isn't something that keeps creating new `MailCheckThread` objects?

Comment: Yes i'm shure. After some researches i'm trying to reinstall VS. Thank you for help anyway.

Comment: I would not expect reinstalling VS to help with a code issue.

Comment: At first glance it seems that you're creating new threads in a loop and never exiting any of the threads.

Comment: MailMessage (from Client.GetMessage) is a disposable object that needs to be released when he's finished with it.

Answer (score 0):

The memory is coming from your MailMessage object. You need to Dispose it when you are done with it.

Comment: I can't dospose it, i need this infinite loop to check the mailbox any 15 seconds.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Every time you call `Client.GetMessage()`, you are creating a new message object which takes up more and more memory. If you want to solve your problem, you need to dispose the message.

Comment: Your `msg` object isn't reused in the loop.  That explanation makes no sense, I agree.